# Strange behavior of htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My goal is to redirect an entire domain to another. Every URL of the old domain shall redirect to the root URL of the new domain.

To achieve this I'am doing:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.google.de/
```

Problem is that when I test it on `http://localhost/randomPath` then it redirects to `http://www.google.de/randomPath`, but not to the root URL of google.de.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Seems like so: `redirectMatch 301 ^/ http://newsite.com`. Found it here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/, scroll down to May 19, 2011, Ryan Burnette.

Comment: wow, how could I overlook the ^ char?! :D that's even better! thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah cool, I was myself stunned if there is no `$` missing at the end, so thought about one char only missing. ;) And by this you have the SEO thing fitted also. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` for finer control on rules like matching Host name etc.:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.de/? [L,R]
```

`?` in the end of target URI will strip off any existing query string.

Comment: If you do `RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.de/? [L,R=301]` you also have the SEO thing fitted. ;)